# Liferay: Export Dynamic Data List Display Table to Excel

Tags: excel, export, liferay, dynamic-data, datalist

I am using the Dynamic Data List Display in Liferay and I am trying to export all the data to an XLS file. Is there an easy simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, unfortunately.

I think it would be possible and not too difficult to implement a `DDLXLSExporter` class in an Ext plugin using Apache POI (and it would be a great contribution for Liferay), but at this time the easiest way is to export the DDL in CSV and then import it in Excel.